# Undefiend index

Tags: php, html, database, forms

When I send my form to another page it says: `Notice: Undefined index: gebruikersnaamRegistreren in on line 55`
 this for every name of the inputs

HTML Code

```
<form action="RegistrerenSucces.php" method="POST">
<fieldset id="inputs">
<input id="gebruikersnaam" type="text" name="gebruikersnaamRegistreren" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam " required />   
                        <input id="paswoord" type="password" name="paswoordRegistreren" placeholder="Paswoord" required />
                        <input id="voornaam" type="text" name="voornaamRegistreren" placeholder="Voornaam" required />
                        <input id="achternaam" type="text" name="achternaamRegistreren" placeholder="Achternaam" required />
                        <input id="email" type="email" name="emailRegistreren" placeholder="E-mail adres" required />
                        <input id="straat" type="text" name="straatRegistreren" placeholder="Straatnaam en huisnummer" required />
                        <input id="postcode" type="text" name="postcodeRegistreren" placeholder="Postcode" required />
                        <input id="gemeente" type="text" name="gemeenteRegistreren" placeholder="Gemeente" required />
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="actions">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Registreren" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbuser='root';
    $dbpassword='usbw';
    $dbdatabase='computingstore';


    $paswoordEncrypted = hash('sha512',$_POST['paswoordRegistreren']);


    print_r($_POST);

    /*Database verbinden*/
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost , $dbuser ,$dbpassword , $dbdatabase);

$query = ("INSERT INTO gebruiker (gebruikersnaam, paswoord, voornaam, achternaam, e-mail, straatnaam, postcode, gemeente) 
VALUES 
('".$_POST['gebruikersnaamRegistreren']."',
'".$paswoordEncrypted."',
'".$_POST['voornaamRegistreren']."',
'".$_POST['achternaamRegistreren']."', 
'".$_POST['emailRegistreren']."', 
'".$_POST['straatnaamRegistreren']."',
".$_POST['postcodeRegistreren'].",
'".$_POST['gemeenteRegistreren']."')");

mysqli_query($link,$query);

/*Verbing afsluiten*/
mysqli_close($link);


?>
```

How can i fix this error i have been looking for it for 2 days now.

Comment: Try to use prepared statements in mysqli

Comment: Hi, what does the `print_r($_POST);` gives?

Comment: As a fellow dutch person, i advise you to write your code in english.

Comment: It posses id field in your table

Comment: Your code is very open to SQL injections and is therefore very insecure. Magically changing `mysql` to `mysqli` does not fix this. You have to take use of the `mysqli` features such as prepared statements and binding values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Look at your developer tool's console.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `isset` to determine if the index is defined and assign an empty value if it is not, and see if the problem resolves.

For example, use the following in the second page:

```
isset($_POST['gebruikersnaamRegistreren']) ? $_POST['gebruikersnaamRegistreren'] : "";
```

instead of

```
$_POST['gebruikersnaamRegistreren']
```

repeat this for all the fields for which you are having problem .

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to work perfectly. Try to use prepare for your queries though. Nevertheless I recommend you to check for any javascript issues.